# How to add CSS for specific pages in RefineryCMS?

Tags: css, refinerycms

Following along to the tutorial at http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started which says to

[image: instructions]

Seemed simple enough. So I created `app/assets/stylesheets/about-page.css` wtih some test code

```
p { 
  color: green; 
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

But that sitll got applied to the home page. 

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not what is meant.. the about-page refers to an id so it's like this using SCSS syntax with, say, styles.css.scss which is included by application.css automatically using the asset pipeline:

```
body#about-page {
  p {
    color: green;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you the right answer, but instead you could also use body id's, so each *individual page* has an *id* of it's page name in the *body*. That way it is even more specific to target your css. At least that's what I do using Wordpress:)